# Finding z score from mean when we know z score from median and mode?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, median

I'm taking an intro stats course and I have the following as a homework question.

> A data point from a symmetric distribution is known to be 3 standard deviations above the median of the distribution, and 2 standard deviations above a mode of the distribution.
>
> What is the z-score of the data point?

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Think about the definition of a z-score, what it means to have a symmetric distribution, and what constitutes useful information.

Comment: Symmetrical distribution will have mean = median, and 3 SD above mean implies $Z = 3.$ It says 'a mode', presumably indicating several modes, and so that part is just a distraction.

Comment: @BruceET Not all distributions have a mean, though one with a standard deviation will